# Unexpected token … ESLINT - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm using ESLINT and prettier on the VSCODE with the following config

I've already installed babel-eslint package

eslint.rc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readable",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readable"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "jsx-a11y", "import"],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      "error",
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ],
    "global-require": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "argsIgnorePatter": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

User Settings:

```
"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  }
```

And I'm receiving this message error

> Unexpected token ...

Comment: wrap every thing in a one curley braces{}. i suspect the error is throwing because it's  not a valid json. i don't know for sure, but i'll start from there...

Comment: JSX syntax is not the same as supporting React. React applies specific semantics to JSX syntax that ESLint doesn't recognize. Recommend using **eslint-plugin-react ** if you are using React and want React semantics.